Set jvm -XX:MaxRamPercentage=80 in docker container
I am running a docker container and I have CMD ["java", "-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80", "-jar", "imgretrieval.jar"] in the docker file. When I run the docker using docker run imageName , i can see this value being passed to docker container ,I have attached image of ps- ef

When I check jvm flags, they are not updated. Please see the below image:

I have also tried with JAVA_OPTS , it still gives the same behaviour. Any help will be appreciated.
My requirement is to make MaxRamPercentage configurable so that it can be passed via env variable in rancher

Please post textual output as text, not as screenshots.

@Mark Will take care of it in future

The reason is that the -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal is only applied to that specific run of Java. It does not show the flags of any other java process, and given you don't specify -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80 when you call java with -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal, it shows the default of 25%.
In short, all flags given on the commandline only affect that specific execution of Java.

Thanks @Mark Rotteveel, So does this mean MaxRamPercentage =80 has worked and I am not able to print that properly. Is there a way to display flags for different java process

@user3300327 See for example Is there any way to show the flags being used in a running JVM?
